# Javascript OOP prototype functions return undefined

Tags: javascript, oop, scope

I'm trying to understand OOP in javascript and wrote those two files. My problem is the unexpected result of the prototype functions: undefined.

Did I miss something or did something wrong?

Module:

```
/*jslint node: true */

function User(tid, tname, ttype) {
    'use strict';
    this.id = tid;
    var name = tname,
        type = ttype;

    console.log("user: " + this.id + " created.");
}

User.prototype.getName = function () {
    'use strict';
    return this.name;
};

User.prototype.getType = function () {
    'use strict';
    return this.type;
};

module.exports = User;
```

And this implements the class:

```
/*jslint node: true */
var User = require('./User');

var userlist = [];

function init() {
    'use strict';
    var namelist = ['Boz', 'Nash', 'Joe', 'Angel'],
        i = 0,
        tUser;

    for (i = 0; i < namelist.length; i += 1) {
        tUser = new User(i + 1, namelist[i], 0);

        userlist.push(tUser);

    }
}

function print() {
    'use strict';
    var tString,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < userlist.length; i += 1) {
        tString = "User Entry:" + i + " | ";
        tString += userlist[i].getName() + " | ";
        tString += userlist[i].getType() + " | ";
        tString += userlist[i].id;
        console.log(tString);
    }
}

init();
print();
```

And this is the output:

```
user: 1 created.
user: 2 created.
user: 3 created.
user: 4 created.
User Entry:0 | undefined | undefined | 1
User Entry:1 | undefined | undefined | 2
User Entry:2 | undefined | undefined | 3
User Entry:3 | undefined | undefined | 4
```

Comment: there is no name property on your object instances, only _id_

Comment: I wanted to make the variables name and type private so that they get only a value once when the object is instantiated. Then only the getter functions get the values. I assume that's not possible then?

Comment: there are no such thing as private properties in JS. ok, well there is a really ugly way to enforce private properties using non-strict methods (via arguments.callee.caller), but i doubt that's what you want.

Comment: thanks @dandavis I vote for the rfornals reply and edit my code accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is how your variables are declared and assigned:

Try ...

```
function User(tid, tname, ttype) {
    'use strict';
    this.id = tid;
    this.name = tname;
    this.type = ttype;

    console.log("user: " + this.id + " created.");
}
```

The variable assignment make it a locally accessible variable; using this allows the prototypes access to the variables.  Using the `this` assignment, the variable is assigned to the object `User` in your case.

Comment: I wasn't saying `this` is scope, but scope is the issue ... will reword.

Comment: Scope: it depends on perspective; when he was creating the variables using var, they were scoped inside the function only.  We can argue the point, but I will clear this in my answer to end this commentary.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use private variable then:

```
this.id = tid;
this.name = tname,
this.type = ttype;
```

Using `var` as in your example:

```
this.id = tid;//available in other functions
var name = tname,
    type = ttype;//won't allow you to access in other functions
```